Using Nuxt and html-to-image for render a page as a graphic
I have used html-to-image to create image from HTML code in my Nuxt project.
Is it possible to create a page in /pages directory to create and render just image with headers like 'Content-type: image/png' to look like URL to static image?
Note: Not saving image anywhere, render everytime when URL is open.
